# C# Function that searches an array and creates subgroups based on user input and a prerequisite

Tags: c#, algorithm

The project is a game called cheating hangman, where the user sets their guess limit, word length, and makes a guess. There large list of words that is read into an array, then narrowed down into a smaller array based upon the given word length. So far I have been able to take in and validate all user input but I have been trying to figure out an algorithm to make subgroups out of the narrowed down array.

What needs to be done- When the user makes a one letter guess, an algorithm that checks each word in the array to see where the letter is, and makes groups out of each "word family". For instance if an 'e' is guessed, then there would be a group made for every word with e at `pos[0]`, one for `pos[1]`, all the way through the end of the `wordlength + 1` for words without the letter.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CheatingHangman
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool rightGuess = false;
            int i;
            int wordLength;
            int guessNumber;
            string guessString;
            char guessChar;
            char[] madeGuesses = new char[26];
            List<string> possibleWords = new List<string>();
            List<string> narrowedWords = new List<string>();

            //read dictionary.txt, add its contents to an array
            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\WCU\Current Classes\Game Development\dictionary.txt");
            string[] words = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\WCU\Current Classes\Game Development\dictionary.txt");

            //ask the player for character length + greeting + read, parse, and validate user input
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to [CHEATING] Hangman, please specify the word legth you would like to play with! (1 - 30)\n");
            wordLength = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while(wordLength < 1 || wordLength > 30)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Oops! You entered a number that is out of the range. Please try again, entering a number that is between 1 and 30");
                wordLength = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            //ask player for number of guesses (1 - 25, 26 is whole alphabet), read, parse, and validate user input
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of guesses you would like to take/nThe number must be between 1 and 25!\n");
            guessNumber = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while(guessNumber > 25)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You can't guess the whole alphabet you bum!\nPlease enter a number between 1 and 25\n");
                guessNumber = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            while (guessNumber < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You gotta guess at least once!\nPlease enter a number between 1 and 25\n");
                guessNumber = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            //Searching through the words[] array to pick out all strings with word length input by user
            for (i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                if (words[i].Length == wordLength)
                {
                    possibleWords.Add(words[i]);
                }
            }

            //possibleWords.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

            //Takes the users guess, validates it, loops for another try until they win or lose
            for (int l = 0; l < guessNumber; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Take your guess!\n~Remember: only put in valid characters (A - Z), you have " + guessNumber + " guesses in total.\n");
                guessString = Console.ReadLine();
                guessChar = guessString[0];

                //****************************************************************************************************//

                for (int m = 0; m < wordLength; m++)
                {
                    Console.Write("_ ");
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
                if (guessNumber == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("YOU LOSE, pfff loser");
                }
                guessNumber--;  //need to wrap this in a decision structure to decrement only if the guess was wrong
                Console.WriteLine("You have " + guessNumber + " guesses left\nYour guesses so far have been: TEST");
            //*****************************************************************************************************//

                while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(guessString))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("C'mon! You gotta give me something here.\nTry again, this time try following directions and enter a letter.\n");
                    guessString = Console.ReadLine();
                    guessChar = guessString[0];
                }
                while (!Char.IsLetter(guessChar))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("C'mon buddy! Gotta guess a letter from A to Z. Do it right this time!.\n");
                    guessString = Console.ReadLine();
                    guessChar = guessString[0];
                } 
            }   
            //Console.WriteLine(guessString + "\n" + guessChar);

            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public string[] Narrow(int wordlength, char a, string[] orgwordlist, string[] newWordArray) //narrow the list down based on word families
        {
            newWordArray = new string[5000];
            for(int i = 0; i < orgwordlist.Length; i++)
            {
                while (orgwordlist[i].Length == wordlength)
                {
                }
             }

             return newWordArray[];
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ Way too much code here that's unrelated to the specific question. Please clean it up so that we have what you've attempted to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly i would use a [dictionary](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-dictionary) with the word as a key and the position as a value.
Something like this :

```
            List<String> narrowedWords = new List<String>();
            char letter = 'e';
            Dictionary<String, Int32> wordFamilies = new Dictionary<String, Int32>();

            foreach (String word in narrowedWords.Where(obj => obj.Contains(letter)))
            {
                var index = word.IndexOf(letter);

                wordFamilies.Add(word, index);
            }
```

And `narrowedWords.Where(obj => !obj.Contains(letter);` are the others

EDIT

You can do this

```
 narrowedWords.Where(word => word.Contains(letter));
```

It is to filter out all the string that doesn't contains your selected letter.
The .Where return an IEnumarable and the foreach will then use it.

You can do it without pre filtering your list :

```
        List<String> narrowedWords = new List<String>();
        char letter = 'e';
        Dictionary<String, Int32> wordFamilies = new Dictionary<String, Int32>();

        foreach (String word in narrowedWords)
        {
            if (word.Contains(letter))
            {
                var index = word.IndexOf(letter);
                wordFamilies.Add(word, index);
            }
        }
```

You should read about [Data Structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/) and [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries)

Comment: excuse my ignorance, im new to c#, in (obj => obj.Contains(letter)) is obj a keyword? Or is it to be replaced with the string that is being examined? Also, wouldn't this only create two structures, one with words that contain the letter and one with words that do not?

Comment: see my edit no it is not a keyword it is more like the name you give to the object being iterate on